Benchmark Neural Networks on High-Dimensional Functions
For a personal project, I am interested in benchmarking certain neural network architectures in the context of high-dimensional function approximation. Specifically, I am interested in continuous, smooth, Hölder, and Sobolev functions defined on $[0,1]^d$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Does anyone know if a standard list of high-dimensional functions is commonly used in the literature to benchmark such models? For example, in the optimization literature, there is a standard list of functions, such as the ones found here, to benchmark various optimization algorithms.

If no such list is available, how should one construct a representative list of functions? This choice will introduce an inductive bias in the problem, so I'd like to ensure the list is as representative as possible.


Thanks!
